# Hubspot CRM notifications - how to avoid people seeing when I read a mail

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, notifications

Our sales people use Hubspot CRM. I don’t. Maybe there is an account for me but I have never logged in as far as I remember.

I use Outlook Mail Client on both phone and laptop for accessing my email. When salespeople send an email to me they get a notification of when I read the email. How does this happen? I mean I am not accessing the email through Hubspot. How can I disable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does this happen?

As, given your comments to another answer, it's apparently not using a read receipt, it might be [a web beacon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_beacon). This is most often just an image that is fetched from some server and includes tracking details in its URL.

For that to work, you apparently allowed displaying remote images. Disabling that will help then; see Microsoft's [Block or unblock automatic picture downloads in email messages](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Block-or-unblock-automatic-picture-downloads-in-email-messages-15e08854-6808-49b1-9a0a-50b81f2d617a).

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: When I use outlook to see the raw email, I see embedded links to t.sidekickopen69.com - which is a site owned by hubspot. My setting is actually to not download remote images, I guess this was downloaded because email came from the same domain as mine - I am just guessing - I will disable remote images download for all emails - no exceptions & try.

Answer (score 1):

For laptop:

Step 1: Launch Outlook 2013.

Step 2: Click the File tab at the top-left corner of the window.

Step 3: Click Options in the column at the left side of the window. This is going to open a separate Outlook Options window.

Step 4: Click the Mail option in the column at the left side of the Outlook Options window.

Step 5: Scroll down to the tracking section, then click the option to the left of Never send a read receipt.

Step 6: Click the OK button to close the window and save your changes.

Comment: When someone requests a read receipt, I get a popup for that and I always say no and I didn't get any for the mails I am referring to.

Comment: This is a different case - the emailer has not asked for a request receipt, this is Hubspot CRM doing something.

Comment: I don't use hubspot, and can't help you any further sorry.

Comment: The question was about hubspot - it's there right on the title.

Comment: Note that attribution is required for otherwise this is just plagiarism; this seems to have been taken from http://www.solveyourtech.com/how-do-you-turn-off-read-receipts-in-outlook-2013/